# Strange tabs-names characters in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, encoding, character-encoding, ide

I am getting strange tabs-names characters in Eclipse IDE.

(Operating system - Win10x64. Software - Eclipse x64 for java developers)

**Buggy tabs:**

[image]

**Correct in the pop-up window:**

[image]

What may be the problem?

Comment: It is a issue with the fonts on your system see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965)

Comment: I've set every font as Consolas and it worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse tabs are broken how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323694/eclipse-tabs-are-broken-how-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

**This is suggested by [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449).**

The issue is described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965).

I have set every font (I don't know witch is required) as consolas and it worked for me.