# Eclipse tabs are broken how to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just downloaded eclipse but it shows broken language so. how can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Some weird font setting?

Comment: This is a problem with the font settings on your system see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965)

Comment: thanks, I solved a problem with the font

Comment: @greg-449 Is there a question where you answered that not only with a comment so we can close this question as a duplicate? I found only duplicates ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62970368/6505250) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63151885/6505250)) with your helpfull comment but not as an answer.

Comment: @howlger No I haven't answered anywhere because I don't use Windows so I don't know what the exact solution is!

Comment: @greg-449 The solution is to set a font (e.g. _Tahoma_ or _Verdana_) in _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_ for _View and Editor Folders > Part title font_ that is shown correctly in the _Preview_ of the preference page.

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by the font settings in Windows. It is described in [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965) Eclipse bug report (closed as not an Eclipse bug).

You should be able to fix it in Eclipse by changing the "Part Title" font - Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts, in the "View and Editor Folders" section change the "Part title font" to something that displays correctly.