# Eclipse IDE doesn't show window-titles properly

Tags: java, eclipse, text, ide, text-rendering

When I open the Eclipse IDE the window titles don't show text properly, not all but most texts related to the IDE are jagged and glitchy, anyone knows what might be the issue?

Things I have tried:

- Restarted Eclipse multiple times (both closing and opening, and also; File -> Restart)
- Changed the fonts
- Updated the IDE and everything within it to the latest version:
  Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
  Build id: 20210312-0638
  OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
  Java version: 15.0.1
- Changed the appearance(s)
- Changed the encoding(s)
- Restarted the computer
- Also I'm using the Windows 10, and OS and Drivers are updated to the latest version at the time of posting this problem
- I searched in/with Google, Stackoverflow, and other search engines with different wording, and all there was were issues with in-editor text rendering/formatting (As you can see in the picture other texts appear fine, like the project itself)

P.S. I don't have the issue with other IDEs I use; like Android Studio (IntelliJ), although I've seen the same issue on Android Studio which used to get fixed with a simple restart, which later they patched the bug as well, so idk if I'm missing something or not, any help would be appreciated

[image: Eclipse IDE window-titles text rendering issue]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling eclipse?

Comment: @CactusCoder I've found a way around it for now, I will try later, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64323694/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 Just checked your solution there, and no! It doesn't work! The solution I provided was the only one that works at the moment! I literally mentioned here that I have tried different fonts and it didn't work sir, my question was far more detailed than just "I just installed Eclipse"! And I'm talking about plus half a year after, a newer different version with all sorts of newer patches, which was different, not nice of you to simply flag as duplicate

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for unflagging, hopefully my recent and more SEO friendly question will be easier to find for those who might benefit from avoiding the headache I had

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution or a way around it, I now am pretty sure it is an IDE's bug

It seems to be a problem with the theming option, what I did was changing the themes to see whether it's gonna get fixed or not, and what I missed was I didn't check all the themes! One appears to be fixing the issue and that is the "Classic" theme only, the only one that works currently

Here's where to find it:
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Theme (dropdown menu) -> Classic

Note: Even disabling theming won't fix the problem for some reason, only selecting "Classic" seems to be working at the moment, hopefully they will fix it soon