# How to change the native Language within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, native

Eclipse Version

Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211

Yesterday my Login dialog looked like this.

[image]

At the end of the day, Eclipse was closed.
This morning, opened Eclipse, the program compiles and running the same program displays the following Login dialog.

[image]

What changed?
How do I change this back?

Doing a search and only returns how to change the "programming" language.

Comment: Possible this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64323694/2670892

Comment: That link pertains to issues within Eclipse. Everything within Eclipse (Text and tabs) are correct. It is only the Login box that appears when execute that there is an issue.

Comment: Yes, but it still looks like a fonts problem rather than language.

Comment: The same number of characters indicates that this is a font problem rather than a language problem. The login dialog is part of your application, not of Eclipse, right?

Comment: Correct. Running the program outside the Eclipse and it is as expected. So, if a Font issue within Eclipse only at run-time, where would one view/change that setting?  I can only find the Font setting for the windows within Eclipse and not for the running application.

Comment: In the run configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_. What is the result when using this on the command line? Might be also an encoding problem.

Comment: Show Command Line :   C:\Java\Corretto11_Eclipse\jdk11.0.6_10\bin\javaw.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:55807 "-javaagent:C:\Eclipse\Eclipse2020\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\225\0\.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "C:\Eclipse\Eclipse2020Project\QuickSetUp\myApp\bin;myPackage.runThis.MyProgram username USER password PASSWORD

Comment: Please add this to your question. What was the result running this command on the command line?

Comment: Running via the command line using the above command and the results are the same with the weird characters. I guess we eliminate Eclipse as the cause?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is not the cause. What is your working command line? Is it the same Java VM `C:\Java\Corretto11_Eclipse\jdk11.0.6_10`?

Comment: I have a few Java versions and changed the one within Eclipse to point to a different version, rebuilt and it is ok now. The strange part I have used this configuration for over a year. Strange that all of a sudden, this happened. Thanks for the trouble-shooting ideas.

Comment: I'm glad it's working now. I'm not sure, but it might also be caused by the fonts installed on your system that have been changed by the installation/update of another application or operating system (e.g. by Microsoft Office or by a Windows update).